# How to run jar Files in web Application

Tags: java, chat

Now I have two .jar files: one is a chat Client and the other one is the chat Server. They are running fine on my desktop application, but now I want to upload them to run on my website. What is the best method for doing this? I have the following files:

```
chatclient.jar
chatserver.jar
```

Can some one please advise on how to put them in my web page without having to download them when a user clicks on them?

Comment: have you explored the option of using javascript (web sockets/xhr-polling) for implementing the client side?

Comment: isn't the client jar, supposed to be on the client machine?!

Comment: You could run the chatserver.jar on the server, and put chatclient.jar inside an applet, in order for the users to be able to run it inside a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not provide enough information. 
What would you like to achieve? 
What technologies are you using inside the JARS?
Why not package the server jar with a [web application](http://www.j2eevideotutorial.com/2012/05/how-to-create-java-ee-web-app-without.html) ? 
Is your client a desktop application, if so, why not to put it in the client's classpath? 
Maybe consider having the client implemented in JavaScript using jQuery for example and some web sockets technology, 
or maybe using some java web framework or tookit like GWT or Apache Wicket?